# What does operator ':=' mean?

Tags: c, gcc, syntax, pthreads, colon-equals

I am trying to compile pthreads for MSVC2015 and found some strange code.

```
localPtr->wNodePtr->spin := PTW32_TRUE;
```

What is this line doing?

Comment: I did some some searching on the web, and the best i could determine is that this is just another way to perform assignment, ie (x = 5). The way of assigning things with x := 5 is used in some other languages.

Comment: You can use debugger and check behavior, it is not standard in C.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/BrianGladman/pthreads/blob/master/ptw32_OLL_lock.c#L578 That is extremely odd and probably a typo... Edit: Or not, seems to be used in more than 1 place. C++ operator perhaps? Is that even possible?

Comment: This stackexchange question may help you >> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101716/in-pseudo-code-what-does-mean

Comment: But does the code compile?

Comment: The file in question doesn't seem to get compiled when you build the project, there's no mention of it anywhere. So my guess is that it's work in progress, containing a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others pointed out `:=` is not a valid C-operator.

However, this "operator" `:=` is found twice in [the current "*PThread for Windows*" source release which seems to be as of v2.9.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/files/).

Both occurencies appear in `ptw32_OLL_lock.c`, which proclaims to "*implements extended reader/writer queue-based locks*", but does not seem to be part of the `pthread*.dll` build, so the file `ptw32_OLL_lock.c` is not passed to the compiler.

Interesting enough the source file in question contains an `int main()` and is not in the `test`sub-directory.

All in all this seems to be alpha, beta or it's simply noise, so just delete it.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, `C` standard does not specify anything about `:=` operator. So, most likely, it's not standard `C`.

However, AFAIK, some languages, which use the `=` as comparison operator, to separate the *assignment* from *comparison*, use `:=` as *assignment* operator. [Example: Pascal,  postgresql]

In some other cases, it carries a meaning that the variable is getting *defined and assigned* in the same step, to differentiate with normal  assignment elsewhere. [Example: GO]

Answer (score 2):

:= is not a valid operator in C.

It does however have use in other languages, for example ALGOL 68. Basically, for what you want to know, the := in this example is used to assign the variable PTW32_TRUE to localPty->wNodeptr->spin

This is done mostly to remove any ambiguity in code, as to avoid using '=' for assignment.

Comment: Algol68 also has other similar operators such as: +:= (for adding to or appending to a string), +=: (for prefixing to a string), also -:=, *:=, /:=, %:=(int division) and %*:=(mod);  Also non-operators like :=:=(juggle) and =:= (swap) and :=: (pointer comparison) ... cf. [Dyadic operators with associated priorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68#Dyadic_operators_with_associated_priorities)

Answer (score 0):

":=" is assignment to variable in Pascal syntax, while equality test is "="